# How to create digital sign and protect PDF file from changes

Tags: encryption, pdf-generation, digital-signature, x509

I'm trying to create a way to encrypt and block a PDF file form any changes.

I've found this little snippet, but something is not so clear for me. This works with a library called "SPIRE":

```
String pfxPath = @"..\Demo.pfx";
            PdfCertificate digi = new PdfCertificate(pfxPath, "e-iceblue");
            PdfSignature signature = new PdfSignature(doc, page, digi, "demo");
            signature.ContactInfo = "Harry";
            signature.Certificated = true;
            signature.DocumentPermissions = PdfCertificationFlags.AllowFormFill;
```

but I'don't understand what they mean to for the parameter page:

> PdfSignature signature = new PdfSignature(Spire.Pdf.PdfDocumentBase document, Spire.Pdf.PdfPageBase page, );

Other way. I found this tutorial on MSDN. 
But this works with XML files. 
[How to: Sign XML Documents with Digital Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745.aspx)

Could this work with PDF too, seeing is PDF based on XML?

Comment: PDF is not based on XML and you need a specialized function that offers digital signing and encryption of PDFs. There exist several libraries for signing PDFs, but I can't say about encryption (especially certificate-based encryption) - the only one I know about is PDFBlackbox package of our SecureBlackbox product.

Comment: I don't know SPIRE either, and just like @Eugene I can only name an alternative library, iText. For samples have a look at the Java samples for [Chapter 12: Protecting your PDF](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=12) in [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/), also available as [C# translations](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx).